# Make not producing all the expected libraries

Tags: makefile, msys, googlemock

I'm trying to make "google mock" but I'm only getting one library: gmock_main.a

Why is gmock.a not being produced? The four .o files are produced.

Thanks,

Barry.

```
# A sample Makefile for building both Google Mock and Google Test and
# using them in user tests.  This file is self-contained, so you don't
# need to use the Makefile in Google Test's source tree.  Please tweak
# it to suit your environment and project.  You may want to move it to
# your project's root directory.
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#
#   make [all]  - makes everything.
#   make TARGET - makes the given target.
#   make clean  - removes all files generated by make.

# Please tweak the following variable definitions as needed by your
# project, except GMOCK_HEADERS and GTEST_HEADERS, which you can use
# in your own targets but shouldn't modify.

# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file, or if you want to use
# a copy of Google Test at a different location.
GTEST_DIR = ../gtest

# Points to the root of Google Mock, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file.
GMOCK_DIR = ..

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR = ../test

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
CPPFLAGS += -I$(GTEST_DIR)/include -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = gmock_test

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# All Google Mock headers. Note that all Google Test headers are
# included here too, as they are #included by Google Mock headers.
# Usually you shouldn't change this definition. 
GMOCK_HEADERS = $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/*.h \
                $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/internal/*.h \
                $(GTEST_HEADERS)

# House-keeping build targets.

all : $(TESTS)

clean :
    rm -f $(TESTS) gmock.a gmock_main.a *.o

# Builds gmock.a and gmock_main.a.  These libraries contain both
# Google Mock and Google Test.  A test should link with either gmock.a
# or gmock_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.  It's fine if your test only uses features from Google
# Test (and not Google Mock).

# Usually you shouldn't tweak such internal variables, indicated by a
# trailing _.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
GMOCK_SRCS_ = $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GMOCK_HEADERS)

# For simplicity and to avoid depending on implementation details of
# Google Mock and Google Test, the dependencies specified below are
# conservative and not optimized.  This is fine as Google Mock and
# Google Test compile fast and for ordinary users their source rarely
# changes.
gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gmock-all.o : $(GMOCK_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/gmock-all.cc

gmock_main.o : $(GMOCK_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/gmock_main.cc

gmock.a : gmock-all.o gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gmock_main.a : gmock-all.o gtest-all.o gmock_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a sample test.

gmock_test.o : $(USER_DIR)/gmock_test.cc $(GMOCK_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/gmock_test.cc

gmock_test : gmock_test.o gmock_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here. I'll bet you're giving it the command `make all`. The comment

```
#   make [all]  - makes everything.
```

is misleading. In fact, `make all` makes only `gmock_test` (and the things which that target needs, namely `gmock_main.a` and the four object files). If you want to make `gmock.a`, you have a couple of choices:

1) `make gmock.a`

2) Add `gmock.a` to the `all` target, like this:

```
all : $(TESTS) gmock.a
```

3) Write a rule for some other thing, like an executable, which actually needs `gmock.a`:

```
real_thing: gmock.a
    ...
```